# What would be the social and political consequences if a major country decided to prohibit driverless cars?

Tags: economy, political-theory, transportation

In the news, there's been talk of countries banning petrol and diesel cars by 2030-2040, but what if a major country - say for example; Canada, United Kingdom, Spain, Italy and South Africa; decided to prohibit driverless cars and make it illegal for businesses to run any services pertaining to them?

What would be the major political and social consequences if these nations did such a thing when hypothetically speaking, other nations had driverless cars? How would it affect international relations, trade, their standing on a global scale etc.?

Currently, this issue is overshadowed by things like Brexit etc. but I thought I'd ask.

I'm new to politics.stackexchange so apologies if this isn't formatted properly as a question.

Comment: Hi and welcome, but speculation is discouraged. Statistics could be found about existing cross border trucking, or about how rail service switches gauges in some places, or left hand to right hand drive change overs work, but it would need to be tied to politics as described in the [help].